# SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement: no surrounding iteration statement

Tags: node.js, callback, promise, continue

getting error "SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement: no surrounding iteration statement "
I am using node js as server
express 4.16.4

-----------------function definition-------------------

```
function createCSV(jsondata){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ //<----errorline
        jsondata = jsondata.replace(/DEGREE/g, '°');
        console.log(jsondata);
        jsondata = JSON.parse(jsondata);
            var machineid = jsondata["Machine ID"];
        var success = true;
        //validation of data
        console.log(format);........so on
```

------------call----------------

```
webapp.post('/json', function(req, res){

    createCSV(req.body).then(function(positive){ <----call

        res.send(JSON.stringify(positive));

    }).catch(function(err){

        console.log(err);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(err));

    });

});
```

----------------------Error-------------------------

SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement: no surrounding iteration statement
    at new Promise ()
    at createCSV (/home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/server.js:295:9)
    at /home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/server.js:203:2
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/server.js:138:2
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/cookie98/Dhruvin/Projects/Polyweld/zip/WebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
{}

Comment: Please show the whole code. Probably there's a `break` or `continue` statement where it doesn't belong

Answer (score 1):

[Dhruvin modi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8614829/dhruvin-modi)'s comment on a deleted answer:

> ohh thanks a lot ...there was a spelling mistake "continuous" converted to "continue"